# TB-03: sync issue (on Live 9)

Tags: ableton, sync, bass, electronic

Well, I have a TB-03 synced through Ableton. When I press "play" for the first time after opening a project, the TB-03 is correctly synced with the rest of the song, everything works perfectly...until I hit "stop". When I hit "play" again, the TB-03 doesn't seem to start its pattern from the beginning, but from a random point (and always from a different one every time I "stop/play/stop" the project). The result is that the rest of the song plays correctly while the 03 is just totally out of place. Actually, I have to close/re-open the project to have the pattern back in time (until I'll hit "stop" again). It's weird and annoying. I have no idea what is going on, neither how to fix it. Any ideas ?

My setup:

MIDI OUT (Focusrite Scarlette 2i4) > MIDI IN (TB-03)

In "Live 9" > "Options" > "Preferences" > "MIDI Sync", the switchs "Track" & "Sync" of the Input and Ouput (Scarlette 2i4) are "ON" (yellow).

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just another hint. It is not necessary to install the USB drivers for the tb-03 but just the "pattern" setting on the (OUT) midi clock is necessary.
I am using just the MIDI cable to sync the TB-03 (USB just for power, not data). 
I have a MOTU Midi express and I set the "pattern" MIDI sync mode on the specific OUT port where the 303 is connected. 
By the way I have also to adjust the midi clock delay to 45 ms to achieve the correct timing.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the solution, hope it will help someone if I share it, here is what I have done:

- update the 03 firmware driver (Roland.com website)
- then some new Input/Output Midi Ports "TB-03" have been created in
  Live 9/Options/Preferences/Midi Sync (until now I only had the one
  related to my external sound card).
- in Output TB-03/Midi Clock Type, choose "Pattern" instead of "Song"
- And of course "Track" and "Sync" are in "ON" position.